# T-SQL convert BigInt into Date

Tags: t-sql, type-conversion

I used to work this way :

`select cast(cast(20171002 as varchar) as date) AS BigInt_into_Date`,

but is it possible, to achive the same with single use of `convert()` function ? 
Conversion between `bigint` and `datetime` is explicite, so `expression` argument in `convert` is needed, so mayby we also could convert into `date`

Comment: Not related to the question, but still worth reading - [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 2):

It *is* possible to convert from BigInt to *DateTime*.

However, the numeric value for October 2nd 2017 is 43008 (days since Jan 1, 1900).

20171002 is really a string representation of a date stored as a number - hence your need for the double cast.

And no - I don't think it's possible to perform any simple arithmetic to get from 20171002 to 43008 :-)

Comment: do you see any reasons why dates are stored as bigints in our SQL Server 2012 database ? Does it improve performance ?

Comment: I really couldn't hazard a guess as to the design decision in this case.  I can't see that storing the date in this way has any benefit at the SQL Server level.  Maybe it's related to an application level decision.  Sorry I don't have anything concrete for you.